# How to execute selenium test cases on the basis of html tag

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute my selenium test cases on the basis of HTML tag value like :

```
<meta name="survey name" content="ABC Car">
```

Content is basically event type and I have 4 event types.

Comment: Please add some more content to your post. Some code with what you already tried.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the content attribute as following:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@name='survey name']")).getAttribute("content")
```

Based on the value of the content attribute, you could execute the desired conditional code.